# using getOffsetHeight with async data after render in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below code is simple, but it's ok impropriate in my opinion. Basically I try to calculate the height of a list. But what's a better solution than doing a setTimeout hack? I tried componentDidMount, but that doesn't guarantee the data is loaded.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      users: null
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get("https://randomapi.com/api/6de6abfedb24f889e0b5f675edc50deb?fmt=raw&sole")
      .then(response => this.setState({ users: response.data }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.userElem.offsetHeight);
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <div ref={elem => (this.userElem = elem)}>
          {this.state.users &&
            this.state.users.map(o =>
              <p>
                {o.first}
              </p>
            )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

demo https://codesandbox.io/s/j46o2656vy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the api call inside [**componentWillMount**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) do it inside [**componentDidMount**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) method, and use [**setState**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) callback method to check the element height.

Like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://randomapi.com/api/6de6abfedb24f889e0b5f675edc50deb?fmt=raw&sole")
    .then(response => {
        this.setState({ users: response.data }, () => {
            console.log(this.userElem.offsetHeight);
        }) 
    });
}
```

Or you can also use [componentDidUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) method, it is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

Comment: componentWillMount act the same like constructor so why there's still componentWillMount? what's that for?

Comment: it plays a great role in server side rendering as per [**doc**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount): *This is the only lifecycle hook called on server rendering. Generally, we recommend using the constructor() instead.*

Comment: I used componentDidUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *[componentDidUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)* and check your **this.userElem.offsetHeight** variable there.Also, i'd change *componentWillMount* with *componentDidMount*. You can read more [here](https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/).

Comment: the article claim componentWillMount act the same like constructor so why there's still componentWillMount? what's that for?

Comment: Most of the time you don't need componentWillMount, however you can do setState inside it based on the initial props instead of doing this.state = {} in the constructor and it will not trigger another render call.